# Excel How to sum range, which is more than one column?

Tags: excel

is it possible to do something like:
=SUM((K6*H6):(K10*H10))

I have the following, and am trying the calculate the total cost, which is hours in week * rate. What is the best way to do this?

[image: Excel table]

Comment: It looks like a case for `SUMPRODUCT`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as an array formula

```
={SUM((K6:K10)*(H6:H10))}
```

Enter with `Ctrl + Shift + Enter`

Comment: Thank you! THat worked. Now for an added complexity. If i filter the table, how can i have the calculation respect the filter?  I tried: =SUBTOTAL(109,SUM((L2:L6)*(H2:H6))) but that didn't work.